# How to use Context and AlertDialog with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, android-context

so i was trying to implement an alart dialog with a EditText in a fragment heres the code:
1.prompt_dialog.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Type your reminder title : "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextDialogUserInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

2.MainFragment.java

```
public class ReminderFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

        final Context context = this;

        public ReminderFragment() {
                    // Required empty public constructor
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment_layout,container,false);

                Button openDialog = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.openDialogButton);
                openDialog .setOnClickListener(this);


                return layout;
            }
        public void onClick(View view){

                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompt_dialog, null);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context);

                // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
                alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
    }
```

but on the Context variable `final Context context = this;` there an error saying

```
Incompatible Types:
        Required: android.content.Context
        Found: com.example.user.packgename.MainFragment
```

i tried using the context on another class that extends `Activity` class and used this code final Context context = this; it wokrs
just fine, with my case maybe its because its extending from the `Fragment` class.

so how can i solve the problem?is there any other way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: use getActivity(), inplace of context in Fragment class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace all uses of `context` and use `getActivity()` instead of it.

All basic four components of an Android application extend `Context` which comprise of - `Activity`, `Service`, `BroadcastReceiver` and `ContentProvider`. The application itself too extend `Context`.

To perform operations related to UI, you need to use `Context` of an `Activity` like displaying an `AlertDialog`.

```
final Context context = this;
```

This line is valid as long as it is written within the scope of any of the components listed above. It won't work in a `Fragment` because it does not extend `Context` of its own, it uses parent `Activity`'s context.

Comment: You can accept the answer so that others don't come here looking for an unanswered question.

Comment: "Have their own Context" is misleading. Those classes `extend Context`, so they are a Context, they don't "have one".